# Multilingual ASP.NET Web Site doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, multilingual, app-globalresources

[Here is the link, where author explains how to a build multilingual website](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/192968/Allow-users-to-select-the-user-interface-language)

When I run the code, I get such an error mesage **"An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode."**

Then I found such an workaround in web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    .
    .
    .
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Now the website works for me, but is shown only in russian, not in english or greek. I am new to ASP.NET, so don't clearly understand source's LanguageModule class, should I somehow modify it?

Comment: its a complicate, and if you do not understand what the code do, then how some explain that ?. First of all the code on the example try to find from the browser what language to use. Second have made resource for more than one language (this is the difficult) and third ha place on the html page a language selection.

Comment: Did this code work for you? Have you tried the website? I'm downloading the source code, running it, but the UI language doesn't change when I change the language from Hyperlinks given in website. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I really like to help you, but I can not debug your code, and the informations you give can not help. Really I am sorry. Yes this code works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 types of pipeline modes in IIS, integrated and classic.  The error you are getting is symptomatic of having your web.config arranged in the classic configuration.

Integrated mode provides more flexibility as both IIS and ASP.NET functionality are executed in the same pipeline, instead of 1 after the other.

It might be possible the the project was configured and hosted on a website configured to run under integrated mode.  If this is the case, hosting the Website yourself in an application pool which is set to  classic mode, may get you going.

Another thing to check is to ensure things like the HttpModule are registered in the correct manner.